# Trying to send post and always get bad request

Tags: java, api, post, request

i'm trying to send the post as below:

```
curl -X POST https://app.referralsaasquatch.com/api/v1/{tenant_alias}/rewards/account/{accountId}/user/{userId} \
       -u :API_KEY \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -d '{
   "type": "CREDIT",
   "cancellable": true,
   "unit": 'credit-in-cents',
   "assignedCredit": 150*100,
   "currency": EUR
}'
```

- API_KEY: API_KEY_VALUE
- TENANT_ALIAS: test_ai38kl5mysg8n
- Authorization: Basic Base64.encode(API_KEY)

  ```
  public static void executePost() {

  // TODO code application logic here
  String STRURL = "https://app.referralsaasquatch.com/api/v1/" + "test_ai38kl5mysg8n" + "/rewards/account/"
          + ActionGetRsqInfo.IDINTIFIRE + "/user/" + ActionGetRsqInfo.IDINTIFIRE;

  System.out.println(STRURL);

  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  try {

      DataOutputStream printout;
      url = new URL(STRURL);
      urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      urlConn.setDoInput(true);
      urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
      urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
      urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      urlConn.setRequestProperty("API_KEY", "API_KEY_VALUE");
      urlConn.connect();



      JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

       json.put("assignedCredit","1500");
       json.put("cancellable", "true");
       json.put("name", "Dollar Credit");
       json.put("type", "CREDIT");
       json.put("unit", "CENTS");

        // Send POST output.
          printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
          printout.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));
          printout.flush();
          printout.close();
          int HttpResult = ((HttpURLConnection) urlConn).getResponseCode();

          if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
              String line = null;
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              br.close();

              System.out.println( sb.toString());

            }

          else {
              System.out.println("bad URL    " + ((HttpURLConnection) urlConn).getResponseMessage());

          }

      }

      catch (MalformedURLException e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      catch (JSONException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      finally {
          if (urlConn != null)
              urlConn.disconnect();
      }

    }
  ```

Comment: please provide us the error you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use HttpURLConnection to connect to https, try HttpsURLConnection, or other clients supporting https instead

```
URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)urlConnection.openConnection();
```

Also try using

```
  OutputStreamWriter printout= new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
  printout.write(requestObject.toString());
```

instead of

```
 printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
 printout.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: tried it also didn't work,

still go to code:
else {
    System.out.println("bad URL    " + ((HttpURLConnection) urlConn).getResponseMessage());

   }

Comment: Can you give more details on HTTP result? what is the error code and may be message returned?

Comment: printout.write(requestObject.toString());

write method only accept integer or byte array

Comment: please note that you should use   OutputStreamWriter instead of DataOutputStream

Comment: now the result is 403, do u think it is the Authorization

 -u :API_KEY \ ??????

does it mean this? Authorization: Basic Base64.encode(API_KEY)

Comment: urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+"Base64CODE"); that's what i send now

Comment: you were right about OutputStreamWriter, i just tried DataOutputStream because i was stuck, if you may please explain to me why i should use OutputStreamWriter?

Comment: but the tricky part was the Authorization so the documentation said:
       -u :API_KEY \
that means i should encode the API key with BASE64.encode i use to send the API key encode it and then set it in the header value but with no luck

             urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+"Base64.encode(API_KEY);
i should've send API_KEY + : the ":" colon with API_KEY because Base64.encode expect username:password
so in this case the API_KEY was the username
so the string i should send to encode "API_KEY:"